# MathJax configuration in MO ==> not displaying bottom left messages

Tags: support, mathjax

I noticed that on MO website, MathJax is usually not displaying messages on the bottom left angle of the screen. While there are always those messages on my own website like for the page [Math Counterexamples](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-differential-equation-with-no-solution/).

Are you using a special MathJax configuration? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about. The bottom left corner of your site displays “Proudly powered by WordPress”, which has obviously nothing to do with MathJax.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the “Typesetting math: 54%” status info? See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html .

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the [MathJax user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users) or some other [MathJax support forum](http://www.mathjax.org/contact/).

Comment: In particular see the `showProcessingMessages: true` setting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MathJax.